# CUDA compiler or emulator for windows

Tags: windows-7, cuda

Is there any compiler or emulator for CUDA on Windows?

I heard there is an emulator which can be installed in Visual Studio, but I want something rather than Visual Studio.

Please tell me if there is any solution for testing CUDA code on Windows.

Comment: What do you mean by testing CUDA code? What kind of testing?

Answer (score 2):

The **NVCC (NVIDIA CUDA Compiler)** ships with the **[CUDA Toolkit](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_develop.html)** for Windows. There used to be an **emulation mode**, but it has been discarded starting from CUDA 3.0. There are open-source projects which offer some kind of emulation.

NVIDIA also provides the **[Parallel NSight](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nsight.html)** tool, which enables GUI debugging of CUDA code within Visual Studio.

Also, you can compile CUDA from the command-line, if that is a Visual Studio alternative that suits you. To compile from the command-line, first open the **Visual Studio Command Prompt**, and then type:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_12 YourCudaFile.cu
```

The `-arch` option is used to specify the CUDA architecture. `sm_12` for example indicates an architecture with **Compute Capability** of 1.2.

Comment: could you please tell me how can I compile CUDA using the command line?